# "Fs.writeFile is not a function"

Tags: javascript, json, filesystems

I want to write data that I have received from another file to a JSON file that I can use again in a Python script. However, my IDE returns the following error:

> TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function

I have tried substituting `const` with `var`, `import` with `require`, and `fs` with `fs-extra`.

file.mjs:

```
let currentSkillLevel = "Beginners"; 
let skillToBeAcquired ="Python";

const fs = import('fs');

let data = {};
data["Current Skill level"] = currentSkillLevel;
data["Skill To Be Acquired"] = skillToBeAcquired;

let inputJson = JSON.stringify(data);

fs.writeFile("input.json", inputJson);
```

Comment: Have you actually tried running the code? It's possible your IDE is using the wrong linter - eg. a plain Javascript one.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, how would I check that? I have ran the code in Visual Studio Code. The exact error is:
fs.writeFile("input.json", inputJson);
   ^

TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function
    at .../file.mjs:12:4
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)

Node.js v18.17.0

Comment: `import('fs');` - dynamic imports give you a promise, so `fs` is one. It's not the module. Either use static import or `await` the import.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
let currentSkillLevel = 'Beginners';
let skillToBeAcquired = 'Python';

const fs = require('fs');

let data = {};
data['Current Skill level'] = currentSkillLevel;
data['Skill To Be Acquired'] = skillToBeAcquired;

let inputJson = JSON.stringify(data);

fs.writeFile('input.json', inputJson, (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else {
    fs.readFileSync('input.json', 'utf8');
  }
});
```

if you want to use the syntax with **import** this is the code

```
let currentSkillLevel = 'Beginners';
let skillToBeAcquired = 'Python';

import { writeFile, readFileSync } from 'fs';

let data = {};
data['Current Skill level'] = currentSkillLevel;
data['Skill To Be Acquired'] = skillToBeAcquired;

let inputJson = JSON.stringify(data);

writeFile('input.json', inputJson, (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else {
    readFileSync('input.json', 'utf8');
  }
});
```

remember to add this to your package.json

```
"type": "module"
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you!